# HTTP POST rails 3 - json - 406 & 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, http, rest, devise

I am having trouble sending data through HTTP REST. When I try and POST json data through the chrome extension 'Simple REST Client' I get a 500 internal server error stating "The document does not have a valid root". When I curl I get a 406 error. But when I leave the data filed empty in both the client and curl a blank document is created! I have changed the json text to every possible valid combination and putting the data back in that the GET produces but no luck!

My controller code is:

```
def create
@verify = Verify.new(params[:verify])

respond_to do |format|
  if @verify.save
    format.html { redirect_to( :back, :notice => 'Verified') }
    format.json { render :json => @verify, :status => :created, :location => @verify }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @verify.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    format.json  { render :json => @verify.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Sample json

```
{"www" : "wwww"}
```

I'm using Mongoid and Devise gems (tried removing before_filter from controller but that made no difference).

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3 adds a root element to json by default in activerecord, since you're using mongoid, try adding this to your `mongoid.yml`

```
include_root_in_json: true
```

Comment: Added the code to the `mongoid.yml` but still getting the same errors. Also added `self.include_root_in_json = true` to the model and `@verify.include_root_in_json = true` to the controller but also no change.

Comment: Damn, have you checked exactly what does the `render :json => @verify` returns? Have you checked what is this "document does not have a valid root" error on the Chrome extension? Out of that I really have no idea what could it be